# How to identify errors in bibtex?

Tags: bibtex

I have obtained this error after compiling .bib file. What does the error mean, please? How to find out where mistakes are? Also, I have got that all citations are multiply defined. However, I have each of them only one time in the .bib file.

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2017/Debian)
The top-level auxiliary file: thesis.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: title.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: preface.aux
The style file: plainnat.bst
A level-1 auxiliary file: chapter1.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: chapter2.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: chapter3.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: chapter4.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: chapter5.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: chapter6.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: chapter7.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: epilog.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: bibliography.aux
Illegal, another \bibstyle command---line 3 of file bibliography.aux :
  \bibstyle : {plainnat} I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
Illegal, another \bibdata command---line 4 of file bibliography.aux :
  \bibdata : {bibliography} I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
Database file #1: bibliography.bib
(There were 2 error messages)
Process exited with error(s)
```

Comment: unless you show the. bib file, I don't think there is any way to guess what could be an issue

Comment: It helps to format the error message so that it is not on a single line. Then you see that BibTeX complains about multiple `\bibstyle` and `\bibdata` commands, which means that your document contains several invocations of `\bibliographystyle` and `\bibliography`. Each of those commands must be called exactly once in your document. (Here "in your document" means in your *complete* document. If your document is made up of several `.tex` files, the commands may still only appear once in total and not once per `.tex` file.)

Comment: Thank you very much. It works now.